How can I switch between databases in a multisite environment using the entity API?
I'm working in a multisite environment and need to switch between databases based on certain conditions. I successfully switched the active database connection using Database::setActiveConnection() in my custom code, which worked fine with direct SQL queries.
public function loadUserByExernalId(string $external_id): ?User {
    $id = '3332';

    Database::setActiveConnection('other_db');
    $db = Database::getConnection();

    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = :uid", [':uid' => $id]);
    $users = $query->fetchAll();
    dump($users);
}

and knowing that this code returns correct connection to other_db:
 dump(Database::getConnection()->getConnectionOptions()); die;


array:12 [▼
  "database" => "other_dv"
  "username" => "root"
  "password" => "root"
  "prefix" => ""
  "host" => "db"
  "port" => "3306"
  "namespace" => "Drupal\mysql\Driver\Database\mysql"
  "driver" => "mysql"
  "collation" => "utf8mb4_general_ci"
  "init_commands" => array:2 [▶]
  "autoload" => "core/modules/mysql/src/Driver/Database/mysql/"
  "pdo" => array:6 [▶]
]

Issue: However, when I tried to use the Entity API to load a user with the same method, it didn't work as expected.
public function loadUserByExernalId(string $external_id): ?User {
    $id = '3332';
   
   Database::setActiveConnection('other_db');
    $user = $this->userStorage->load($id);
    dump($user); // OUTPUT: null
}


You’ll need to flush the caches after switching db connection

@Clive even after clearing the cache i still get null with entity API

You can't guarantee by this method that the user storage will use the alternate connection. It will have its own existing database connection already built - check the constructor for SqlContentEntityStorage. If you want to switch database connections and use the entity API, you'll probably need to be a lot smarter about it. I'd consider instead using REST API calls so you can keep your DBs on separate domains.
